Complex Kummer Surface and Cyclic Covering
There are two references which provide the context for this question: first is page 9 of Lectures on K3 surfaces by Huybrechts of the Kummer construction, and the second is Chapter 1 Section 17, page 55, of "Compact Complex Surfaces" edition 2 by Barth et al.
Start with a 2-dimensional torus $A = \mathbb{C}^2/\Lambda$. There is an involution $i: A \to A$ where $x \mapsto -x$. Blowing up the 16 fixed points, we obtain a compact complex surface $\tilde{A}$ which has 16 exceptional divisors $E_1, \cdots, E_{16}$ from the blow-up procedure. The involution $i$ extends to an involution $\tilde{i}: \tilde{A} \to \tilde{A}$ which is identity only on $E_1, \cdots, E_{16}$, and acts on $\tilde{A} \setminus \{ E_1 \cup \cdots \cup E_{16} \}$ as expected. Let $X = \tilde{A}/\tilde{i}$ denote the quotient. This $X$ is the Kummer surface constructed.
Here is my question: It is claimed on page 9 that $\pi_* \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{A}} \cong \mathcal{O}_X \oplus \mathcal{L}^\vee$ where $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes 2} \cong \mathcal{O}_X(\bar{E_1} + \cdots + \bar{E_{16}})$, where $\pi: \tilde{A} \to X$ is the quotient map and $\bar{E_j}$ denotes the image of $E_j \subset \tilde{A}$ in $X$ -- why is this true?
My current hypothesis is this: if one knows that there exists a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ such that $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes 2} \cong \mathcal{O}_X(\bar{E_1} + \cdots + \bar{E_{16}})$, and $\tilde{A} \to X$ is the cyclic covering constructed from $\mathcal{L}$ in the sense of Chapter 1 Section 17 of Barth et. al, then indeed $\pi_* \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{A}} \cong \mathcal{O}_X \otimes \mathcal{L}^\vee$ by lemma 17.2 of Barth et. al. Then my question becomes: how do we know that such a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ exists, and if so, how do we know that this quotient map actually comes from the cyclic covering construction?
Thanks for any time and help provided.

If $f \colon X \to Y$ is a flat double covering  then
$$
f_*\mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{O}_Y \oplus \mathcal{L}
$$
and the algebra structure of the right side is induced by a morphism
$$
\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{O}_Y.
$$
This morphism vanishes on a divisor $B \subset Y$. In fact, this is
the branch divisor $B$ of the covering. Indeed, looking at the algebra structure of the right side on $B$ and on its complement, it is easy to see that the double covering is ramified over $B$ and is etale over its complement.
Finally, the branch divisor is the image of the ramification divisor, and the latter is exactly the fixed point set of the involution.
